# Extract and explode embedded json fields in apache spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm completely new to spark, but don't mind if the answer is in python or Scala. I can't show the actual data for privacy reasons, but basically I am reading json files with a structure like this:

```
    {
      "EnqueuedTimeUtc": 'some date time',
      "Properties": {},
      "SystemProperties": {
          "connectionDeviceId": "an id",
          "some other fields that we don't care about": "data"
      },
      "Body": {
        "device_id": "an id",
        "tabs": [
            {
              "selected": false,
               "title": "some title",
               "url": "https:...."
            },
            {"same again, for multiple tabs"}
        ]
     }
   }
```

Most of the data is of no interest. What I want is a Dataframe consisting of the time, device_id, and url. There can be multiple urls for the same device and time, so I'm looking to explode these into one row per url.

| timestamp | device_id | url |

My immediate problem is that when I read this, although it can work out the structure of SystemProperties, Body is just a string, probably because of variation. Perhaps I need to specify the schema, would that help?

```
root
 |-- Body: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EnqueuedTimeUtc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SystemProperties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionAuthMethod: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionDeviceGenerationId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionDeviceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contentEncoding: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contentType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- enqueuedTime: string (nullable = true)
```

Any idea of an efficient (there are lots and lots of these records) way to extract urls and associate with the time and device_id? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for extraction. Basically you can use `from_json` to convert the Body to something that is more structured, and use `explode(transform())` to get the URLs and expand to different rows.

```
# Sample dataframe

df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|Body                                                                                                                                          |EnqueuedTimeUtc|SystemProperties|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|{"device_id":"an id","tabs":[{"selected":false,"title":"some title","url":"https:1"},{"selected":false,"title":"some title","url":"https:2"}]}|some date time |[an id]         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Body: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EnqueuedTimeUtc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SystemProperties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionDeviceId: string (nullable = true)

# Extract desired properties

df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "EnqueuedTimeUtc as timestamp", 
    "from_json(Body, 'device_id string, tabs array<map<string,string>>') as Body"
).selectExpr(
    "timestamp", 
    "Body.device_id", 
    "explode(transform(Body.tabs, x -> x.url)) as url"
)

df2.show()
+--------------+---------+-------+
|     timestamp|device_id|    url|
+--------------+---------+-------+
|some date time|    an id|https:1|
|some date time|    an id|https:2|
+--------------+---------+-------+
```